# convert strange hex phone number to normal digits

Tags: c++, c++11, hex

I have a phone number represented as: `AA A3 AA A1 A3 A7 A9 A7 A4 A9` and I want to convert it to normal digits: `0301379749`?

Comment: AA(16) = A(16) * 16(10) + A(16) = 10(10) * 16(10) + 10(10) = 170(10) and so on.

Comment: Is the number saved in memory? If so, how? Is it a char array/pointer? Or do you have it saved in a file? Or are you supposed to input the numbers in a prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    std::string str = "\xAA\xA3\xAA\xA1\xA3\xA7\xA9\xA7\xA4\xA9";

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '\xAA') str[i] = '\x00';
        str[i] = (str[i]&'\x0F') + '0';
    }

    //or
    std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char &c)
    {
        if(c == '\xAA') c = '\x00';
        c = (c&'\x0F') + '0';
    });

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your digits seem to be offset by 0xA0, with the digit '0' represented as 10 rather than 0 (0xA0 + 10 = 0xAA).

So, for each digit, subtract 0xA0, then take modulo 10:

```
const unsigned int digit = (weirdHexValue - 0xA0) % 10;
```

Borrowing some code from @hidayat, here's an example of how to convert:

```
int main()
{
    std::string str = "\xAA\xA3\xAA\xA1\xA3\xA7\xA9\xA7\xA4\xA9";

    std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char &c)
    {
        c = '0' + (c - 0xA0) % 10;
    });

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```